# NGX-Virtual Keyboard Angular 6 throws error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

Hello all i want to implement virtual key board I have added to module & included in my html but the above plugin is giving me error can some one help .I have also included in the module in imports array as well.

```
    Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unexpected value 'NgxVirtualKeyboardModule' 
    imported by the module 'ProfileModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    Error: Unexpected value 'NgxVirtualKeyboardModule' imported by the module 
   'ProfileModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
```

This is the ts part

```
import { NgxVirtualKeyboardModule }  from 'ngx-virtual-keyboard';
export const profileRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgxVirtualKeyboardModule
  ],
```

This is the html part

```
<input type="text" value=""
  [ngx-virtual-keyboard]="true"
  [ngx-virtual-keyboard-layout]="layout"
  [ngx-virtual-keyboard-disabled]="false"
/>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant code as well (i.e. your module file) please?

Comment: sure i will just add that

Comment: I have added both ts & html above can u please look at it once @user184994

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for ngx-virtual-keyboard is not updated and the demo application also not working.

This is published 9 months ago later there is no any updates

I will suggest you to use **ngx material keyboard.**

Which will provide custom layouts and lot of other stuffs.

you can refer this link [ngx-material-keyboard](https://github.com/ngx-material-keyboard/core)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: If my input box is at bottom this keyboard shows up & hides that is there any way we can style that & change the keyboard position ?